# Passport.js - use same token for different server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, passport.js

I'm using passport.js and MongoDB for user login and postAPI authentications. However whenever I deploy my node server to another AWS instance, I need to go through the signup process, do the login and get a new token.

I know I can see the saved users and their jwt tokens from MongoDB. Are there anyway that I can copy the token and, when initialize new database, save the same username-jwttoken pair by default, so I can use the same token string (not with password, though it is more easily to be done) to pass the passport authentication test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your deployment process involves tearing everything (application and MongoDB) down & rebuilding from zero, possibly with some seed data but without any of the "live" data in the AWS instance. Here are a couple of ideas:

1. copy all the data from the old MongoDB instance to the new one as part of your deployment process. This will ensure that the users are present on the new instance and (should) ensure that users don't have to go through the signup process again. I'm not too familiar with MongoDB so I don't know how to do this, but I'm sure there's a way - maybe you can copy the data files from one to the other?
2. set up your environment with two servers: a MongoDB server and an application server. This way you can tear down your application and create a new AWS instance just for the application without touching your MongoDB server. Just update the MongoDB connection configuration in your new application instance to point to the same MongoDB server you've been using.

The first option is more suitable if you have a very small application without too much data. If your database gets too large, you're going to experience long periods of downtime during deployment as you take the application down, copy the data out of the old Mongo instance, copy the data into the new Mongo instance, and bring the application back up.

The second option is probably the better one, although it does require some knowledge of networking and securing MongoDB so that only your application has access to your data.